# Adjust percentage

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm stuck on what I would think is a simple problem.

A group of $3$ people are selling a product through a store.

Under the current arraignment, the store gets $30$% of the price the product is sold for. The group of $3$ get the remaining $70$%.

The group of $3$ split up the remaining $70$% as $25$%, $25$%, and $20$%.

If we considered the remaining $70$% as $100$% which would be divided up in the same proportions, what would those percentages be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are confused with the percentages, it is always to better write down statements to make it easier.

If $70$% is equivalent to $100$% , then $25$% is equivalent to ?

$(25*100/70)$ = $(2500/70)$% = $35.715$%

Similarly if $70$% is equivalent to $100$% , then $25$% is equivalent to ?

$(25*100/70)$ = $(2500/70)$% = $35.715$%

Similarly if $70$% is equivalent to $100$% , then $20$% is equivalent to ?

$(20*100/70)$ = $(2000/70)$% = $28.57$%

Hope the answer is clear !

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful